# True or False...Database relation confusion.... I need a bit of explaination for these

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

1. Any two tuples in a relation have different values on at least one
   attribute.
2. Tuples belonging to the same relation are stored in arbitrary order.
3. The programmer can specify the tuples in the same relation to be displayed in a particular order according to the values of one or more attributes.

I would say... True, False, True....

I would like to hear your guys opinions because you people have been in this field longer than I have :)

Thank you guys in advance :)

Comment: I think that you are confusing a relational database with relational algebra, at least some of those concepts seems to be mixed. Besides, these concepts will be very different across database engines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any RDBMS that forces the developer to have non-duplicate rows (tuples). So, in practice, the answers are False, True*, and True.

*Again, in practice, the answer to #2 might be False in some circumstances depending on the RDBMS, but it doesn't have to be and the developer should assume that #2 is True.

Comment: Yea.. 2 is very confusing for me as well. Is there an example that you could give me to prove that it can be false and true? Thanks :) Cheers

Comment: Well, for example, in SQL Server if you have a clustered index on a table the data in the table are sorted based on the values of the index keys. Again, however, not something the developer ought to assume.

Comment: @user1235103 - You would need to look at the documentation of your RDBMS to understand how the data is stored on your disk. There is no implicit order on how the data is stored

Comment: ohh...... so usually the developer should assume true until what type of circumstance occurs?

Comment: @user1235103 - No, you should never assume true about how the data is stored.

Comment: Not entirely correct re: SQL Server. The rows *within* a page can be in any order, only their indices will be in clustered key order. And the pages can be stored physically out of order. And there's still no guarantee that these orderings will or will not affect when rows are retrieved from the table compared to other rows within the same table.

Comment: @Lamak, True means that the tuples (rows) are stored in an arbitrary order, which is definitely what the developer ought to assume.

Comment: @David: *"I don't know of any RDBMS that forces non-duplication of rows (tuples)"* That's because those DBMS are not truly relational :) [Rel](http://dbappbuilder.sourceforge.net/Rel.php) is an attempt.

Comment: A relation cannot have duplicate tuples by definition hence #1 is true. I suspect you are (ab)using the term 'RDBMS' to mean 'SQL product'.

Answer (score 2):

1. True. Two rows that are completely identical must represent, logically, the same tuple. A tuple in a relation (or a row in a table) is basically a statement of truth, e.g. the row ('John Smith',1/1/2000) might mean "The employee named John Smith started employment on 1/1/2000." If a **table** in an RDBMS has the **rows** ('John Smith',1/1/2000) and ('John Smith',1/1/2000), this doesn't make the statement any more true - there is only one *tuple* represented here.* The relational model doesn't say you can't store multiple copies of a row; it only says that if you change one copy, you must make the same change to all the other copies as well; and when you query it, only one of those copies should be used. In practice, it's more convenient/performant to enforce uniqueness with a constraint and only store one physical copy.
2. True (or more accurately: not applicable). The relational model cares not in which order truth statements are stored. The order in which tuples are represented is immaterial to their truth value.
3. Also "not applicable". How results of queries on a relational database are presented to users is outside the scope of the relational model. It really couldn't care less.

(* don't tell me there might be two people named "John Smith" who started work on that particular date; in the relational model, you *must* find something different about those two poor fellows to distinguish them to the database, otherwise, logically, those rows *must* be referring to exactly the same truth statement - if not, there are update and delete anomalies that cannot be resolved - e.g. if "John Smith" suddenly gets sick of being mistaken for *that other* John Smith, and resigns, how would you write the UPDATE statement to set his resignation date?)

Answer (score 1):

> Any two tuples in a relation have different values on at least one attribute.

True. This is a requirement of the relational model.

> Tuples belonging to the same relation are stored in arbitrary order.

Neither true nor false.

It is true that relations have no tuple ordering by definition. However, a relation is a not 'stored'. The quiz master probably meant to say *relation variable* (relvar).

It is true that the relational model has nothing to say on whether a relvar's tuples are stored in a particularly order; rather this is a feature of the DBMS. Most SQL products that are based on contiguous storage allow users to specify a clustered index for a base table that will influence physical ordering on disk. However, the SQL standard has nothing to say about such indexes. There is no reason why relational DBMS couldn't have a similar feature.

> The programmer can specify the tuples in the same relation to be
>   displayed in a particular order according to the values of one or more
>   attributes.

The statement is not true of a relational database language. If a database language had such a feature then the result would not be a relation (it wouldn't be displaying tuples) and therefore the language in question would not be relational.